# How to Match similar like value in two column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
ID       Value1          Value2
AAA-01   Ert we          ert-We
AAA-02   ATT ER          ATT ER
AAA-03   Accept          accepted
AAA-04   Apple           Apple
AAA-05   VEETR           veetr
AAA-06   EERTT           RRFTF
AAA-07   ETYuU           RTTRR
```

From using the above mentioned dataframe, I want to match the similar looking text and give it `TRUE` and `FALSE` value.

Output:

```
ID       Value1          Value2     Status
AAA-01   Ert we          ert-We     TRUE
AAA-02   ATT ER          ATT ER     TRUE
AAA-03   Accept          accepted   TRUE
AAA-04   Apple           Apple      TRUE
AAA-05   VEETR           veetr      TRUE
AAA-06   EERTT           RRFTF      FALSE
AAA-07   ETYuU           RTTRR      FALSE
```

Comment: define *similar looking text*

Comment: @Sotos Where the case of the letter are different but meaning are same and maximum word match in both the column against a unique `ID`.

Comment: Your question is not very clear - how can you measure if meaning is the same?

Comment: @PoGibas I have export the data in excel and apply simple match (i.e B2=C2) but for some unique `ID` i have value in one column like `Grouping` and another column like `group-ing` It gives me false.

Comment: Read about "fuzzy matching".

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach below. No idea if this is going to satisfy your 'similar looking text' criteria outside of this example, but it may give you something to start with.

```
df = read.table(text="ID       Value1          Value2
AAA-01   Ert_we          ert-We
AAA-02   ATT_ER          ATT_ER
AAA-03   Accept          accepted
AAA-04   Apple           Apple
AAA-05   VEETR           veetr
AAA-06   EERTT           RRFTF
AAA-07   ETYuU           RTTRR",header=T)

Value1_txt = tolower(gsub('[^[:alpha:] ]','',df$Value1))
Value2_txt = tolower(gsub('[^[:alpha:] ]','',df$Value2))
df$similar = mapply(function(x,y) grepl(x,y) | grepl(y,x) ,Value1_txt,Value2_txt)
```

Output:

```
      ID Value1   Value2 similar
1 AAA-01 Ert_we   ert-We    TRUE
2 AAA-02 ATT_ER   ATT_ER    TRUE
3 AAA-03 Accept accepted    TRUE
4 AAA-04  Apple    Apple    TRUE
5 AAA-05  VEETR    veetr    TRUE
6 AAA-06  EERTT    RRFTF   FALSE
7 AAA-07  ETYuU    RTTRR   FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that assumes **"similar looking text"** means *first three characters are identical after converting to lower case*:

```
df$Status <- with(
  df, 
  tolower(substr(Value1, 1, 3)) == tolower(substr(Value2, 1, 3))
)
df
      ID Value1   Value2 Status
1 AAA-01 Ert we   ert-We   TRUE
2 AAA-02 ATT ER   ATT ER   TRUE
3 AAA-03 Accept accepted   TRUE
4 AAA-04  Apple    Apple   TRUE
5 AAA-05  VEETR    veetr   TRUE
6 AAA-06  EERTT    RRFTF  FALSE
7 AAA-07  ETYuU    RTTRR  FALSE
```

Where:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID     = sprintf("AAA-%02d", 1:7), 
  Value1 = c("Ert we", "ATT ER", "Accept", "Apple", "VEETR", "EERTT", "ETYuU"), 
  Value2 = c("ert-We", "ATT ER", "accepted", "Apple", "veetr", "RRFTF", "RTTRR")
)
```